# Navigating through datagridview cells with enter key

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, enter

I've tried several combinations but didn't have any success. When button is pressed focus is on yellow (1), I would like  when enter key is pressed, that focus goes to cell (2), then (3) and so on.

[image]

If there are no cell edits, with just enter key everything is fine with this code :

```
 Private Sub DGVBU1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DGVBU1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            Dim CLIndex As Integer = DGVBU1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
            Dim RWIndex As Integer = DGVBU1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
            If CLIndex = 2 Then
                DGVBU1.CurrentCell = DGVBU1.Rows(RWIndex - 1).Cells(CLIndex + 1)
            ElseIf CLIndex = 3 Then
                DGVBU1.CurrentCell = DGVBU1.Rows(RWIndex).Cells(CLIndex - 1)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

But when Enter key is pressed after cell edit it goes down to row+1.

I've also tried this :

```
Private Sub DGVBU1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGVBU1.CellEndEdit
    Dim CLIndex As Integer = DGVBU1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
    Dim RWIndex As Integer = DGVBU1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
    If CLIndex = 2 Then
        DGVBU1.CurrentCell = DGVBU1.Rows(RWIndex).Cells(CLIndex - 1)
        DGVBU1.CurrentCell = DGVBU1.Rows(8).Cells(CLIndex + 1)
    ElseIf CLIndex = 3 Then
        DGVBU1.CurrentCell = DGVBU1.Rows(RWIndex).Cells(CLIndex - 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

...but then enter key send focus from (1) directly to cell (4).

Is it possible to make this work?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If the DataGridView may be intercepting the Enter key in the keydown event. If this is the problem, a solution is to derive the control class and override ProcessCmdKey:

Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As Message, ByVal keydata As Keys) As Boolean

If keydata = Keys.Enter Then
  OnKeyDown(New KeyEventArgs(keydata))
  ProcessCmdKey = True
Else
  ProcessCmdKey = MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keydata)
  End If

End Function

Comment: But that also disables any code that uses Enter key, and with that navigation through DGV with an Enter key.

Comment: That's true. You would need to handle that code separately.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
       Select Case DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
            Case 0
                e.Handled = True
                DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex + 1).Selected = True
            Case 1
                e.Handled = True
                Try
                    DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index + 1).Cells(2).Selected = True
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
       End Select
    End If
End Sub
```